# How to change url dynamically

Tags: angular, angular8

I use to get my blog's data from url's param like below.

```
const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
const newurl = `${serverUrl}/${id}`;
// this.http.get<any>(newurl); // to get data from the server.
```

url looks below

```
http://localhost:4200/blogs/1
http://localhost:4200/blogs/2
http://localhost:4200/blogs/3
```

Now, after I get the data from the server, I would like to add blog title at the end of url like below.

```
http://localhost:4200/blogs/1/First-Title-Url
http://localhost:4200/blogs/2/Second-Title-Url
http://localhost:4200/blogs/3/Third-Title-Url
```

Literally I do nothing with lastly added title in the url but to readable purpose.

Here is my Blog class in back-end

```
public class Blog
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
}
```

Note: title have duplicates.

I am running this project in Asp.Net Core 2.2, Angular 8. How do I change url now?

Comment: If you do not use it for routing purposes, it shouldn't be in the URL.

Comment: @Ramesh but if you need based on title then you need to pass title in route url second param otherwise its work like static and its not okay. you can access your url using this code

`this.http.get<typeasperyouneed>("API_URL").subscribe(response => {
  this.router.navigate([`./${response.title}`],
    {
      relativeTo: this.route,
     queryParams: { title: response.title },
      queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
    });
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **queryParam** to achieve this.

```
constructor(private _router: Router) { }

this.http.get<any>(newurl).subscribe(data => {
      this._router.navigate(
        [],
        {
          relativeTo: this._route,
          queryParams: { title: data.title },
          queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
        });
})
```

This will produce url like:

```
http://localhost:4200/blogs/1?title=First-Title-Url
```

Comment: can we replace `?title` with `/`

Comment: appending with `?` means using queryparam. If you want to use `/` instead, all the titles have to be added in your routes which is not a good way

Answer (score 2):

**Not recommended** because you need to add all the routes in your routes list but this is possible. You just need to update the url with the help of router that you can inject inside constructor like so,

```js
constructor(private router: Router,
            private route: ActivatedRoute) {

}
```

Then after getting response from your API you just need to navigate to the updated url,

```js
this.http.get<any>("API_URL_HERE").subscribe(data => {
  this.router.navigate([`./${data.title}`],
    {
      relativeTo: this.route
    });
});
```

This will navigate you to the this url, but keep in mind all these urls must be declared in your **RoutingModule**. If you think that it is not possible to declare all urls inside routes array, then you must use query params instead.

```
http://localhost:4200/blogs/1/First-Title-Url
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `switchMap` operators to create another request based on the title you get from the first request. The `switchMap` operator cancels all pending request if there is a change in the `paramMap` before it finishes.

```js
const blog$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  switchMap((params) => {
    const url = `${serverUrl}/${params.get('id')}`;
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(
      switchMap((blogTitle) => this.http.get(`${url}/{blogTitle}`))
    );
  })
)
```

Then you can use `blog$` to display the content asynchronously for example like

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="blog$ | async as blog">
  <h1>{{blog.title}}</h1>
  <p>{{blog.body}}</p>
</ng-container>
```

Whenever you change the route (to be more precise: the route paramsMap) it will automatically reload the blog.

Answer (score 0):

`@angular/common` is providing a injectable service [Location](https://v8.angular.io/api/common/Location#location). After injecting it into the component, you can call the [replaceState](https://v8.angular.io/api/common/Location#replaceState) method on it.

But before that, you need to have routes like below. So that, on refresh, you won't get route not match issues, because of dynamic `title` param appended to the URL

```
{
  path: 'blogs/:id',
  component: BlogsComponent,
}, {
  path: 'blogs/:id/:title',
  component: BlogsComponent,
},
```

Observe, calling the same component for both the routes

And now in the component

```
constructor(
  private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  private blogDataService: BlogDataService,
  private location: Location,
  private router: Router
) {
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
    this.blogId = params.id;
    this.title = params.title;
    this.getBlogData();
  });
}

getBlogData() {
  this.blogDataService.getDataByBlogId(this.blogId).subscribe((data) => {
    this.blogData = data;
    if (!this.title) {
      const titleToAppend = data.title.split(' ').join('-');
      const activeUrl = this.router.url;
      this.location.replaceState(`${activeUrl}/${titleToAppend}`);
    }
  });
}
```

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-13-ktvobv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fblogs%2Fblogs.component.ts)